# How do I troubleshoot CheckLib returning false?

Tags: scons

Scons version is 2.3.3. Here is the relevant portion of the build script:

```
if not conf.CheckLib('portaudio'):
    raise Exception(
        'Did not find libportaudio.a, portaudio.lib, or the PortAudio-v19 development header files.')
```

CheckLib is always returning a false value. How do I debug this? I followed it through the Scons source code until it tries to build a small test program but then I could not track it any further.

I tried all the troubleshooting flags suggested in [section 27 of the Scons manual](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.1.0/HTML/scons-user/index.html) but none of them produce any additional output. For example,

```
C:\code\github\mixxx2>scons -Q --debug=findlibs winlib=%WINLIB_PATH% qtdir=%WINL
IB_PATH%\build\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6 hss1394=1 mediafoundation=1 op
us=0 build=%BUILD_TYPE% machine=%TARGET_MACHINE% toolchain=msvs virtualize=0 tes
t=1 sqlitedll=0 mssdk_dir=%MSSDK_DIR% force32=1
```

I don't know what the `-Q` option is for. I have tried omitting it and it makes no difference; I get no additional information on stdout. Just this:

```
[...truncated...]
Checking for C library portaudio... no
ERROR:root:Unmet dependency: Did not find libportaudio.a, portaudio.lib, or the
PortAudio-v19 development header files.
```

Comment: How do you have the library paths set? The library should be found searching through the library paths you provide via the LIBPATH construction variable.

Comment: The build scripts are thousands of lines long. I believe that LIBPATH is set up correctly but I can't be sure. If I had to guess, I would guess that the linker is actually finding the lib but encountering a link error (e.g. linking x86 against x64 or something). I would love to see what commands scons executes and what error (presumably a link error) it encounters when doing this CheckLib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Configure object generates a log file as it is performing its actions, by default the file is *config.log*. According to the [Configure Contexts](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html#configure_contexts) section of the scons man page, the log file can be customized when the `Configure` object is initialized by passing a `log_file` argument.

With a simple SConstruct, I get a config.log file with the build failure.

SConstruct:

```
env = Environment()
conf = Configure(env)    
if not conf.CheckLib('foo'):
    Exit('Can not find foo')
```

config.log:

```
file /home/dbacher/Code/scons-test/SConstruct,line 2:
        Configure(confdir = .sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for C library foo... 
.sconf_temp/conftest_0.c <-
  |
  |
  |
  |int
  |main() {
  |  
  |return 0;
  |}
  |
gcc -o .sconf_temp/conftest_0.o -c .sconf_temp/conftest_0.c
gcc -o .sconf_temp/conftest_0 .sconf_temp/conftest_0.o -lfoo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: Configure: no
```

I would guess this log file is enough for you to diagnose the problem.

BTW, the scons manual describes the `-Q` option as:

> Quiets SCons status messages about reading SConscript files, building targets and entering directories. Commands that are executed to rebuild target files are still printed.

Comment: Excellent! The config.log was sitting right there, I just didn't realize it was a scons file. And yes, it has exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue after an interrupted build. Removing `.sconf_temp/` and `.sconsign.dblite` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

After looking up the --help, I find --debug option is helpful to your situation

```
scons --debug=findlibs    blah blah
```

The verbose information is shown in config.log