# Gem5 Installation: Checking for c library python 2.7 ..no

Tags: python-2.7, scons, gem5

Currently, I am trying to install gem5 simulator on my on MacBook. I have installed the scons. But when I was running the command "scons", the systems says:

**Checking for C library python2.7... no
Error: Can't find library python2.7 required by python.**

I have installed python-dev by using brew as well. I wonder if there is any other dependency I have to install or something compatible with macOS.

Comment: By looking in the source for that error message, we find https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/9fc9c67b4242c03f165951775be5cd0812f2a705/SConstruct#L691 which appears to run `python-config --ldflags`. What is the output of that command if you run it directly on your shell? My working Ubuntu 19.10 build gives `-L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions`. Also consider reporting on the mailing list.

Comment: I directly ran the command "python-config --ldflags". My system gives me -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation Does it work?

Comment: By looking at the code that follows: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/9fc9c67b4242c03f165951775be5cd0812f2a705/SConstruct#L713 it does a `conf.CheckLib` for every `-l` lib returned. You have to understand why that is failing, e.g. ensure that they are all present. This question explains how to debug `conf.CheckLib`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595410/how-do-i-troubleshoot-checklib-returning-false It appears to just compile an empty C hello world with the options.

Comment: cheers. I will do that!

Comment: @CiroSantilli, Hi sorry to bring this up. I ran into the same problem when building gem5. `conf.CheckLib` just could not find python. But I have the same output with you when running `python-config --ldflags`. Any idea to deal with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @FrederickHong Hmm, not sure what is happening. So I'll just recommend the stupid solution that always works: use Docker :-) (and possibly bisect things once you get a working setup) E.g. this talks about the official upstream setup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/350475/how-can-i-install-gem5/1275773#1275773 and here's mine that works on an Ubuntu 20.04 guest: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/d769513efc3825ac4321f6a23f5696b3288450b4#docker Newer gem5 needs python3, and Ubuntu 20.04 only has python3, so things are simpler at that point.